# Display thumbnails of original images saved as blobs in the mysql

Tags: php, mysql, gd, blob, thumbnails

I saved an original image in my database using the following fields:

```
file_name VARCHAR(255)
mime_type VARCHAR(255)
file_size INT
file_data LONGBLOB
```

My PHP code for saving is:

```
$image = $_FILES['image'];
$info = getImageSize($image['tmp_name']);
$query = "CALL saveImageInDataBase('" .        
    mysql_real_escape_string(file_get_contents($image['tmp_name'])) . "', '" . 
    mysql_real_escape_string($image['name']) . "', '" . 
    mysql_real_escape_string($info['mime']) . "', " . $image['size'] . ")";
$result = mysql_query($query);
```

I want to create a thumbnails of original images out of above data in the server (I'm using PHP) in order to display on the site (to display a list of links of images).

Can someone tell me the simplest way to do this?

Comment: why don't you just save the image file on a local directory from your server? it would be a bit easier and on the otherhand the disadvantage of this technique (saving the image file in the database) is that your site will load slower than you would expect because the data needs to be still parsed by the server which is expensive on the processing time

Comment: @juand yes i tried creating and saving thumbnails of images saved on a local directory of my server using the GD library `$save = 'myfile.jpg';
 $file = 'orphinal.jpg'; 
 $size = 0.45; 
 header('Content-type: image/jpeg') ; 
 list($width, $height) = getimagesize($file) ; 
 $modwidth  = $width * $size; 
 $modheight = $height * $size; 
 $tn    = imagecreatetruecolor($modwidth, $modheight) ; 
 $image = imagecreatefromjpeg($file) ; 
 imagecopyresampled($tn, $image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $modwidth, $modheight, $width, $height) ; 
 imagejpeg($tn, $save, 100) ;` but i want to it for images saved on blobs

Comment: @colighto i have already done my site saving images on blobs.It will be a site which contain huge amount of images

Comment: @shehan: If a provided solution worked, please accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing the whole thing wrong.

1. **DO NOT store images in the database.** It makes absolutely no sense in the context of an HTML-drven website.
2. **DO NOT create thumbnails on the fly.** Create them right after upload and store in the files along with original image.

For the particular code you may search either google or this site. There are over 100500 codes written already I believe.

Comment: DO NOT store images in the database. <<< Is this still "BAD IDEA" ?